# Does the IDT is used in Exception Dispatching?

Tags: windows, exception, interrupt, windows-kernel, interrupted-exception

I'm trying to unserstand the flow of Exception Dispatching on Windows and I saw that the Exception Dispatcher doesn't check for handlers on the IDT.
to my knowledge the flow of Exception Handling (for a User mode process) is:
1st Debugger
Exception handler that was written by the proggramer (SEH)
2st Debugger
Exception port -> Subsystem trying to translate the Exception to a signal
Error port -> CSRSS calls WER, which execute a handler that terminates the process

None of these levels includes using the first IDT's entries (those that contain handlers for exceptions like page fault).
So my question is, when these entries are being used and by who?

Comment: it used by cpu at from very begin